# Mongo shell script - How to use libraries?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

In a Mongo shell script I need to read a file to delete documents by _id but I can't import the FileReader library.

I launch script from bash to do simple find() and it works:

```
mongosh --host xxx --port 27017 --username xxx --password xxx --eval "var country='$country';var file='$inputDataFile'" --file scriptFile.js
```

But whenever I try to import a library in the js it shows the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: 
'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType
```

The same js file I call from nodejs and the import is correct.

Right now I do the deletion of _ids contained in a file using nodejs. I would like to find a way to use Mongo shell script for all my queries

Comment: I don't think you can import external files within Mongo's internal Javascript runtime…!

Comment: How do you import the library? It should work, see [Include External Files and Modules in Scripts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/require-external-modules/)

Comment: @deceze, why do you think so? It was even possible in the old legacy shell: [load()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/load/#mongodb-method-load)

Comment: I have not used load() because in the examples it is used when you are logged in mongo shell, mine is launched in an automatic bash process and I have read that --file is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with the help of [Include External Files and Modules in Scripts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/require-external-modules/)

> 1. Create package.json in the same directory as your js
> 2. Add the necessary libraries to package.json
> 3. Install libraries
> 4. Use require to import it

Code

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(country)
console.log(file)
db = db.getSiblingDB('mongotest')

const allFileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
var lines = allFileContents.split("\r")

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  const user = JSON.parse(lines[i]);
  var userId = user._id
  if (!(userId instanceof ObjectId)) {
    userId = new ObjectId(userId);
  }
  db.userChat.deleteOne({ _id: userId })
}
```

Thanks for your help